# Do i need a visa to travel to Mexico as a green card holder with refugee travel document

Tags: mexico, refugees

Today Alaska airlines won't let me on board, because I don't have a visa on my refugee travel document. My original (non-US) passport is expired.
1 year ago I went to Cancun, Mexico with RTD & GC without issues. Is it because of harmful supervisor?

https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico

Effective March 1st 2010, all visitors traveling to Mexico either by air, land or sea are required to present a valid (non-expired) Passport or Travel Document from their country to enter Mexico.
With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico, effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired) Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union).

Comment: The green card and refugee travel document are sufficient. There was no reason to deny boarding for documents, as you had the proper documents.

Comment: no way I am from Mexico and you dont need nothing of course you need your passport and if  you are not a criminal , it is easy come to mexico :)

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience, you do not need a visa to travel to Mexico if you intend to stay there for less than 180 days and You hold the US Visa or evidence of residency.

I visited Mexico in February 2019 and Traveled on Alaska Airlines and Presented the same documents.  I ran on the same problem.

Next time use IATA - TimaticWeb2 and print results from both Alaska's Travel doc link

and take it to CSR or call the supervisor; they are accommodating and swift at @AlaskaAir

For a formal response: https://www.alaskaair.com/content/about-us/contact-us/phone-numbers. Tag them with #iFlyAlaska [Twitterhandle](https://twitter.com/alaskaair)

https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/before-your-trip/international-travel-information